# Ignore specific part of string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My String is

```
I liked TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}, now I play TAG{Fortnite,Fortnite} is Destiny
```

So I don't want to replace "Destiny" from

```
TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}
```

but I want to replace last word "Destiny" with

```
TAG:{Destiny:Destiny}
```

I always want to ignore string in TAG while replacing.

Expected Output:

```
I liked TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}, now I play TAG{Fortnite,Fortnite} is TAG:{Destiny:Destiny}
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the error with your code? Or have you not tried anything as of yet?

Comment: So your desired output would be `I liked TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}, now I play TAG{Fortnite,Fortnite} is TAG:{Destiny:Destiny}`? Describing your output is generally less helpful than actually providing it (when small enough to provide); please read about writing [MCVE]s.

Comment: all things I tried either replace all Destiny strings even in the last Destiny game or none

Comment: You also need to be explicit about your inputs.  If it's just the one string, then replace the last 7 characters and done.  But if it's more general, you may need regex or more intelligent parsing

Comment: seems like you need a regular expression that overlooks whats between `tag{}`

Comment: how to effectively use regular expression that overlooks string between TAG:{}

Comment: Can curly brackets appear in the text separate from the `TAG:{...}` bits? If they can be anywhere, I'm not sure regex can handle it, but if they're restricted, then it should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse your string first to find out which `Destiny` substrings are inside a tag, and which aren't. I have done this below with [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

My use of re.split returns a list of substrings surrounding the regex pattern `TAG:?{.*?}`, and because I enclose the pattern in parentheses, the tags are included in the list as well. In this use of re.split, the non-tags will always have an even index, and the tags will always have an odd index. So I check if the index is even, and if so I replace `Destiny` with `TAG:{Destiny,Destiny}`.

```
import re

s = 'TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}, now I play TAG{Fortnite,Fortnite} is Destiny'
result = []
for i, substring in enumerate(re.split('(TAG:?{.*?})', s)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        substring = substring.replace('Destiny', 'TAG:{Destiny,Destiny}')
    result.append(substring)
result = ''.join(result)
print(result) # TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}, now I play TAG{Fortnite,Fortnite} is TAG:{Destiny,Destiny}
```

This will work as long as you don't have tags nested inside other tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

my_string='I liked TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}, now I play TAG{Fortnite,Fortnite} is Destiny'

match = lambda x: True if len(re.split('(Destiny){1}', x)) == 3 else False 
repl =  lambda x: str.replace(x,'Destiny','TAG:{Destiny:Destiny}') if match(x) else x

l =re.split(r'({.*?})',my_string)
replaced=[repl(i) for i in l]
print(''.join(replaced))
```

output

```
I liked TAG:{Destiny2,the last Destiny game}, now I play TAG{Fortnite,Fortnite} is TAG:{Destiny:Destiny}
```